# Adding a datarow by dynamically reading a text file

Tags: vb.net, datarow

I have a program that reads a text file and creates a datatable dynamically based on the columns in the file.

This seems to work fine.

I then try to read the rest of the text file, creating a data row to add to my table. I'm using the code below but it's not working for me.

view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
            Dim strFieldData As New ArrayList  
            Dim obj As New Object()
            'this code give me 12 separate elements  
            strFieldData = SplitDelimitedLine(strLineOfFile, ",", "|")  

            Dim dr As DataRow  

            For i As Integer = 0 To strFieldData.Count - 1  
                dr = DataForSQLTable.NewRow()  
                dr.ItemArray(i) = strFieldData.Item(i)  
            Next
            'however when I look at the value of dr.itemarray I see System.DBNull for all the fields  
            DataForSQLTable.Rows.Add(dr)
```

I'm obviously missing the trick. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're only adding the last item. You need to move the addition line inside the for loop.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To strFieldData.Count - 1
    Dim dr as DataRow = DataForSQLTable.NewRow() 
    dr.ItemArray(i) = strFieldData.Item(i)
    DataForSQLTable.Rows.Add(dr) 
Next
```

Comment: ended up using code like this                                                <pre><code>Dim strFieldData As New ArrayList
                Dim obj As New Object()

                strFieldData = SplitDelimitedLine(strLineOfFile, ",", "|")

                Dim dr As DataRow
                dr = DataForSQLTable.NewRow()
                For i As Integer = 0 To strFieldData.Count - 1

                    dr.Item(i) = strFieldData(i).section
                Next

                DataForSQLTable.Rows.Add(dr)